# What does it mean if macros in a Lisp are monadic?

Tags: macros, lisp, monads, static-typing

In the [Lux Language introduction](https://github.com/LuxLang/lux) we read:

> Unlike in most other lisps, Lux macros are monadic. The `(Lux a)` type is the one responsibly for the magic by threading `Compiler` instances through macros. Macros must have the `Macro` type and then be declared as macros.

Now I assume that this means that additional type checking information is available at compile time giving you some feedback on the correctness of your code.

But what could be incorrect about a macro that you could find out at compile-time?

My question is: **What does it mean if macros in a Lisp are monadic?**

Comment: The devlog has a blog post on [Macros in Lux](http://luxlang.blogspot.fi/2015/10/macros-in-lux_4.html). That talks a little bit about using monads to simplify parsing macros.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a cursory glance, it seems both "normal" macros and reader macros are monadic in Lux.

For normal macros, they are threading a state of type `Compiler` through. Various macro operations (I imagine `gensym`ing would be an obvious example) require changing this internal state, since they rely on stateful effects like maintaining the next available fresh atom. Threading state (i.e. functions that look like `s -> (a, s)`, getting the initial state as the argument and returning the updated state and the result) exhibits an obviously monadic structure, i.e. given some first step `s -> (a, s)`, choosing the next step `s -> (b, s)` can depend on looking at the intermediate result `a`.

For reader macros, it is a similar story, except the effect in question is the consumption of input. A monadic parser is one that allows previously consumed input to affect the way subsequent input is parsed.

Comment: Great - what benefit do I get over macros in Common Lisp?

Comment: I don't know too much about Common Lisp reader macros, but regular Common Lisp macros are already monadic. It's just that in the absence of static typing of effects like `gensym`, every effect is more of a side-effect, so there's no distinction between the monad of "pure functions" and the monad of "macros".

Comment: The basic idea to realize is that functions with untracked sideeffects are monadic in exactly the same way that pure functions are -- since you can't even tell the difference between the two.